# List content of a directory except hidden files in Perl

Tags: perl, file, hidden

My code displays all files within the directory, But I need it not to display hidden files such as "." and "..".

```
opendir(D, "/var/spool/postfix/hold/") || die "Can't open directory: $!\n";
    while (my $f = readdir(D)) 
    {
       print "MailID :$f\n";
    }
     closedir(D);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Linux system, "hidden" files and folders are those starting with a dot.

It is best to use *lexical* directory handles (and file handles).

It is also important to *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of every Perl program you write.

This short program uses a regular expression to check whether each name starts with a dot.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

opendir my $dh, '/var/spool/postfix/hold' or die "Can't open directory: $!\n";

while ( my $node = readdir($dh) ) {
  next if $node =~ /^\./;
  print "MailID: $node\n";
}
```

Comment: Why do you name the var "$Node"?

Comment: @Infintie: Because it can be a directory entry, a file entry, a symbolic link, or a few other things. Linux [calls its directory index entries *"inodes"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode)

Answer (score 8):

It sounds as though you might be wanting to use the [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) function rather than `readdir`:

```
while (my $f = </var/spool/postfix/hold/*>) {
    print "MailID: $f\n";
}
```

`<...>` is an alternate way of globbing, you can also just use the function directly:

```
while (my $f = glob "/var/spool/postfix/hold/*") {
```

This will automatically skip the hidden files.

Comment: +1 : It's rare to see `glob` used in scalar context, I didn't know it was possible until I saw this answer :)

Comment: @Zaid This is Perl, there's always both a different context. :) When I first started learning Perl, I had a script I tried to figure out, and this was one of the techniques used. `<foo/*>`.

Comment: @TLP: It's important to note that `readdir` will always return a simple file name, while `glob` gives the path as well, according to the directory passed to it.

Comment: @Borodin Did you really just downvote me? Even though I just gave a perfectly good answer?

Answer (score 4):

Just skip the files you don't want to see:

```
while (my $f = readdir(D)) 
  {
     next if $f eq '.' or $f eq '..';
     print "MailID :$f\n";
  }
```

Comment: This is perfect !! I will accept answers in 1 min there is a timer unfortunately

Comment: That will avoid only the pseudo-directories `.` and `..`. Hidden items include anything starting with a dot.